# Customize Jenkins failure message

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I am trying to config Jenkins so that it runs a script to verify the code every time someone pushes their changes to code review branch in Gerrit. My question is regrading the message sent back to Gerrit from Jenkins job.

This is what I see in **Gerrit** report (please note the red box):

[image]

And this is what I see in **Jenkins** report:

```
...    
7 errors

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
Finished: FAILURE
```

I may be wrong but I assume the word `FAILURE` that appears in Gerrit is the same that comes after `Finished:` in Jenkins report. Is there any way I can elaborate on that message and send more useful information back to Gerrit?